# How to caputure Samsung Smart tv remote right,left,center and enter using javascript?

Tags: javascript, samsung-smart-tv

I am learning to create Samsung smart tv HTML web app. I created a hello world app that suppose to change text simultaneously when user press left, right, center or enter button on the remote.The app installs on D series Samsung tv and even displays the Samsung Smart TVand Hello world texts but when I press left,right,center or enter button on remote nothing happens and the text(Samsung Smart TV) doesn't change! Could an expert tell me what is wrong with Main.js ?Thanks in advance.

Folders:

```
CSS
icons
JavaScript
config.xml
index.html
```

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
     <title>Hello World!!</title>
     <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href = 'CSS/Main.css'/>
     <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/API/Widget.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/API/TVKeyValue.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="./JavaScript/Main.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body onload="Main.onLoad();" onunload="Main.onUnload();">

   <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="anchor" onkeydown="Main.keyDown();"> </a>

    <label id="LabelId">Samsung Smart TV!</label>

    <div id='welcome'>Hello world !</div>
</body>
```

Main.js:

```
var Main = {
   // Main object
}

var widgetAPI = new Common.API.Widget(); // Create Common module

Main.onLoad = function () {
  // called by <body>'s onload event
this.enableKeys();
widgetAPI.sendReadyEvent(); // Send ready message to Application Manager
}

Main.onUnload = function()
{
};

Main.enableKeys = function()
{
    document.getElementById("anchor").focus();
};

Main.keyDown = function()
{
    var keyCode = event.keyCode;
    alert("Key pressed: " + keyCode);

switch(keyCode)
{
    case tvKey.KEY_RETURN:
    case tvKey.KEY_PANEL_RETURN:
        alert("RETURN");
        widgetAPI.sendReturnEvent();
        break;
    case tvKey.KEY_LEFT:
        //alert("LEFT");
        document.getElementById("LabelId").innerHTML = "Smart TV - LEFT";
        break;
    case tvKey.KEY_RIGHT:
        //alert("RIGHT");
        document.getElementById("LabelId").innerHTML = "Smart TV - RIGHT";
        break;
    case tvKey.KEY_UP:
        //alert("UP");
        break;
    case tvKey.KEY_DOWN:
        //alert("DOWN");
        break;
    case tvKey.KEY_ENTER:
        document.getElementById("LabelId").innerHTML = "Smart TV - Center";
        break;
    case tvKey.KEY_PANEL_ENTER:
        //alert("ENTER");
        break;
    default:
        alert("Unhandled key");
    break;
}
};
```

Main.css:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
}

#welcome {
   position: absolute;
   left: 50px;
   top: 50px;
   width: 500px;
   height: 50px;
   background-color: #AFAFAF;
   color: #99FFFF;
   font-size: 30px;
   text-align: center;
}

#LabelId{
   position: absolute;
   left: 50px;
   top: 100px;
   width: 500px;
   height: 50px;
   background-color: #AFAFAF;
   color: #99FFFF;
   font-size: 30px;
   text-align: center;
}
```